# Decorator function using *args and **kargs as parameters for its __call__ method,

Tags: python

I'm currently working with a decorated function that is supposed to check a function's annotations if a certain bool is set to True in the decorator class. What I'm a bit confused about is the decorator function's `__call__` method header:

```
def __call__(self, *args, **kargs):
```

and its parameter list.

I understand that its parameters `*args` and `**kargs` are used for the arguments provided to the function, but in the problem I'm dealing with I have to call the original function (which is an attribute in the instance object created from the decorator class named `_f`).

How would I go about calling `_f` with the arguments provided to the decorated function? Should I check to see whether `args`/`kargs` is empty and call `self._f(args)`/`self._f(kargs)` for the nonempty parameter?

Comment: `self._f(*args, **kargs)`? You need to pass *both* to the wrapped function.

Comment: I suggest you take a look at the [packing / unpacking process in Python](http://hangar.runway7.net/python/packing-unpacking-arguments)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you decorate the method:

```
class Foo:

    @someDecorator
    def my_method(self, x, y):
        ...
```

It isn't yet actually a method; it's just a function. Inside your decorator, you treat it as such:

```
def someDecorator(f):
    def _(*args, **kwargs):
        ...
        return f(*args, **kwargs)
    return _
```

When `_` gets called, `self` will be included in the `*args` argument.